# Fetching multiple TFS git repo sources with git submodules

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

I'm facing an issue while trying to access different git sources in TFS Build.

I have 2 repos Test1 & Test2 -  https://tfs.org.com:8080/tfs/collection/project/_git/Test1 (& Test2). Under Test2, I added a sample.txt & .gitmodules file.

.GitModules file has a cmd - `git submodule add https://tfs.org.com:8080/tfs/collection/project/_git/Test1` (Since I want to checkout Test1 contents too while triggering Test2 repo)

Now in Build def (which builds Test2) I checked the option (Checkout Submodules) - and triggered the build. But I don't see Test1's content was checkout in build server. How can I achieve this ?

Note: I have tried with other option that I found online - but no luck.

```
[submodule "Test1"]
    path = Test1
    url = https://tfs.org.com:8080/tfs/collection/project/_git/Test1
```

(The above one is a POC's that I'm testing to make it work in our actual environment, i.e, Azure DevOps - accessing TFS with OtherGit service connection to build and release)

Here is the build Log for Get Sources:

```
2020-10-04T15:16:20.1648800Z Entering TfsGitSourceProvider.PrepareRepositoryAsync
 
2020-10-04T15:16:20.1648800Z localPath=E:\Temp\1\s
 
2020-10-04T15:16:20.1648800Z clean=True
 
2020-10-04T15:16:20.1648800Z sourceBranch=refs/heads/master
 
2020-10-04T15:16:20.1648800Z sourceVersion=1cca491d4af9def54e8e9d11b3c6ffbb226ace21
 
2020-10-04T15:16:20.1648800Z Syncing repository: Test2 (Git)
 
2020-10-04T15:16:20.1648800Z repository url=https://tfs.org.com:8080/tfs/collection/project/_git/Test2
 
2020-10-04T15:16:20.1648800Z checkoutSubmodules=True
 
2020-10-04T15:16:20.2586300Z Running 'git clean -fdx' on E:\Temp\1\s.
 
2020-10-04T15:16:20.5555003Z Running 'git reset --hard HEAD' on E:\Temp\1\s.
 
2020-10-04T15:16:20.6648794Z HEAD is now at 043b897 Updated .gitmodules
 
2020-10-04T15:16:20.6805036Z Starting fetch...
 
2020-10-04T15:16:20.9930080Z Checking out 1cca491d4af9def54e8e9d11b3c6ffbb226ace21 to E:\Temp\1\s with submodules
 
2020-10-04T15:16:21.0398784Z Checked out branch refs/heads/master for repository Test2 at commit 1cca491d4af9def54e8e9d11b3c6ffbb226ace21
 
2020-10-04T15:16:21.0398784Z commit=1cca491d4af9def54e8e9d11b3c6ffbb226ace21
 
2020-10-04T15:16:21.0398784Z Leaving TfsGitSourceProvider.PrepareRepositoryAsync
```

Comment: You should have some logs of the Git checkout process on your build. Can you add those to your question?

Comment: @SorenBjornstad Added the build logs

Comment: @user2153844 I tested it on my side but it worded well. It looks like your steps are correct. Can you follow my steps and try again?

Comment: @user2153844 Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? Feel free to let me know if you're still blocked, I'll try my best to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You must [select the option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#submodules) to download submodules.

[image: Checkout submodules option]

In YAML you must add an explicit `checkout` step

```yaml
steps:
- checkout: self
  submodules: true
```

Comment: Thanks @giulio. But I m using TFS Classic build for now. We are not Implementing in YAML.

Comment: The top screenshot on this answer shows how to use it on Classic.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the steps below and it worked as expected:

1. Create two repositories and initialize.
2. Use "git submodule add" command.
   [image]
3. Now I have a .gitmodules file and a test1 file in my test2 repository
   [image]
4. Create a pipeline and select the "Checkout submodules" option.
   [image]
5. I can see the following logs after running pipelines.
   [image]