# Added Solution to Devops but Existing Website (angular) didnt commit correctly

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure, azure-devops, devops

this might be a combination of issues here is the steps i took:

Created a new solution in Visual Studio 2019 And created 2 projects

i then used powershell to create an Angular Web app and added it to the sln via "add existing web site"

in VS i now see the following:

[image]

I then decided to start setting up the Azure Devops environment and commit the solution to it

Here is where issue 1 arrised, the "regular" projects commited just fine however the
web application did not, this is what i see in Azure devops:

[image]

As you can see the "FestWise-Web" project is seen as a file and when opened it just shows a alphanumeric string inside: "5a485154e242189bf16479881e377550ee5ce7b2"

Shouldn't i be able to somehow have the angular project be added to the Repo as well ?

The second issue is that in VS i see that the source control detects a change to the "FestWise-Web" [submodule]

but when i choose to commit it throws:  **fatal: unexpected sequence in commit output.**

[image]

how can i solve this ?

Comment: You added a second Git repo inside your existing Git repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't i be able to somehow have the angular project be added to the Repo as well ?

Based on your description and screenshots, the `FestWise-Web` is a submodule file.

In Azure Devops, you cannot directly see the specific content in the submodule file on the interface. You can only see a string of IDs representing files.

When you use this repo(e.g. Azure Pipelines), you can still use this files from submodule file.

Here is a ticket about [using submodule repo in Azure Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64197332/fetching-multiple-tfs-git-repo-sources-with-git-submodules/64204893#64204893).

> fatal: unexpected sequence in commit output.

A submodule file has its own repo/work-area. It is similar to adding a second repo to the existing repo.

Therefore, git commit cannot be done directly in visual studio.

I could reproduce the same issue.

[image]

To solve this issue, you need to combine git command in Command Line or Powershell.

```
cd path/to/submodule  # e.g. cd path/to/FestWise-Web

git add --all 

git commit -m "Message"
```

Then you could click the **"Commit All"** Option and the changes will be committed successfully.

[image]

Finally, you could push the changes to Azure Devops. The Id in the submodule file will change at the same time.

[image]